# Deploying Codeigniter to a subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, cloud

I have been battling with deploying a codeigniter website to a subdomain in digital ocean all day.
I have a subdmain a.bcd.com and deploying the site to this domain and launching it from the browser gave this error" `Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid."
I have changed the base_url to be`http://a.bcd.com/ and yet the error persisted.
My route['default-controller'] ='User';
Can anyone offer some tips on the work around this pls?
Thanks

Comment: Silly question, but have you restarted apache after those changes? Also, post your `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'` code.

Comment: make sure ur controller starts with capital letter

Comment: What makes my question silly @Tpojka?. Anyways, I have updated my question to include the route but certainly. The route is fine

Comment: Your server is Linux ?

Comment: Thanks @pradeep for your reply. I did start all my controllers with capital letters.

Comment: Yes, It is  Linux

Comment: Filename name should start with capital.Because Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: Use conventions i have followed but still the error is showing

Comment: use route['default-controller'] ='user';

Comment: @Joseph You misunderstood, I was saying that my question could be silly. Do you have contructor mentod in controller that is calling parent constructor?

Comment: Thanks for clearing it @Tpojka but no offense. Yes i have a constructor method

Comment: Is subdomain location other than domain location in terms of server path?

Comment: @Tpojka, I dont understand your question

Comment: Edit your question and post whole `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'` code.

Comment: Thanks  all and  to  you @Tpojka but the config/routes.php is pretty lean, straight forward and is fine. But  for some weird reason. I decided to upgrade to from 2.x to 3.x and everything worked fine